# UnabIe to Convert.FromBase64String a base64 encoded string

Tags: c#

"eyJwYXltZW50SWQiOiI1ZjBjMmJmZmFiNDRlMjJjNjhiZWUzMDkiLCJjdXN0b21lckRldGFpbHMiOnsiZmlyc3ROYW1lIjoiY3NKb2huMSIsImxhc3ROYW1lIjoiY3NEb2UxIiwidXNlcklkIjoiNWVmNGI1OGZkYjUyZjk1ZGY4NWYwMjg0In0sIm9yZGVyRGV0YWlscyI6eyJvcmRlcklkIjoiNWYwYzJiZmZmYjVkYTIzNTcwYjhjM2JhIiwiY3VycmVuY3kiOm51bGwsImFtb3VudCI6IjU0LjAwIn0sIm1lcmNoYW50RGV0YWlscyI6eyJuYW1lIjoiRENQIn0sImlhdCI6MTU5NDYzMzIxNSwiZXhwIjoxNTk0NjMzODE1fQ"

When I tried **Convert.FromBase64String** on the above string I got an error saying
*The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters*

I even added = symbol at  the end of the string but it didn't work
but when I decode the same string in Notepad++ I get the JSON Data.

Comment: could you please *show us the code in question*?

Comment: Try two : `==`.

Comment: Make sure the received string is exactly the same number of bytes (characters) transmitted.  If you did not receive the entire string that you can get a convert error.

Comment: Notepad++'s extension must be able to account for padding issues. [Your string, when padded with two `=` will decode correctly](https://dotnetfiddle.net/hFjGz9)

Comment: @Crowcoder I did add two == symbols but was unable to decode

Comment: @VikasPandey Without your code I can't tell why it failed but I can tell you it worked when I did it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The string isn't correctly padded as Crowcoder noted. A base64 string can be padded by 0, 1 or 2 equal signs (=), some implementations doesn't care about this but some do (like Convert.FromBase64String). What you want is a string length divisible by 4, if it isn't you pad it with equal signs.

Something like this.

```
var str = "eyJwYXltZW50SWQiOiI1ZjBjMmJmZmFiNDRlMjJjNjhiZWUzMDkiLCJjdXN0b21lckRldGFpbHMiOnsiZmlyc3ROYW1lIjoiY3NKb2huMSIsImxhc3ROYW1lIjoiY3NEb2UxIiwidXNlcklkIjoiNWVmNGI1OGZkYjUyZjk1ZGY4NWYwMjg0In0sIm9yZGVyRGV0YWlscyI6eyJvcmRlcklkIjoiNWYwYzJiZmZmYjVkYTIzNTcwYjhjM2JhIiwiY3VycmVuY3kiOm51bGwsImFtb3VudCI6IjU0LjAwIn0sIm1lcmNoYW50RGV0YWlscyI6eyJuYW1lIjoiRENQIn0sImlhdCI6MTU5NDYzMzIxNSwiZXhwIjoxNTk0NjMzODE1fQ";

if(str.Length % 4 != 0)
  str += new String('=', 4 - str.Length % 4);

Convert.FromBase64String(str);
```

Comment: A better answer, I never noticed that string constructor overload

Answer (score 1):

A snippet to pad the original string:

```
        var base64Source = "eyJwYXltZW50SWQiOiI1ZjBjMmJmZmFiNDRlMjJjNjhiZWUzMDkiLCJjdXN0b21lckRldGFpbHMiOnsiZmlyc3ROYW1lIjoiY3NKb2huMSIsImxhc3ROYW1lIjoiY3NEb2UxIiwidXNlcklkIjoiNWVmNGI1OGZkYjUyZjk1ZGY4NWYwMjg0In0sIm9yZGVyRGV0YWlscyI6eyJvcmRlcklkIjoiNWYwYzJiZmZmYjVkYTIzNTcwYjhjM2JhIiwiY3VycmVuY3kiOm51bGwsImFtb3VudCI6IjU0LjAwIn0sIm1lcmNoYW50RGV0YWlscyI6eyJuYW1lIjoiRENQIn0sImlhdCI6MTU5NDYzMzIxNSwiZXhwIjoxNTk0NjMzODE1fQ";
        var requiredPadding = 4 - base64Source.Length % 4;
        if (requiredPadding > 0)
        {
            base64Source += new string(Enumerable.Repeat('=', requiredPadding).ToArray());
        }
        var result = Convert.FromBase64String(base64Source);
```